# Destruir objetos QWidget de Qt

Tags: qt

Cómo debo destruir los objetos **Qt** usados para crear las GUIs, por ejemplo los `QPushButton`, `QLabel`, etc., debo llamar a `delete` de manera manual o el framework gestiona la liberación de memoria.

```
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Button");
QLabel *lbl = new QLabel("Label");
```

Al terminar debería hacer algo como esto, o no:

```
delete btn;
delete lbl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el objeto **no tiene padre** eres tu el encargado de crearlo y de destruirlo:

```
QWidget* widget = new QWidget;
// ...
delete widget;
```

Ahora, en el momento en el que ese widget posee un padre es el padre el que se va a hacer cargo del ciclo de vida del widget... Al morir el padre, el hijo se eliminará automáticamente:

```
QWidget* widget = new QWidget(parent);

// delete widget;
```

Por supuesto siempre puedes borrar el widget de forma manual, en este caso el widget se desligará del padre antes de borrarse... pero ojo, porque si el padre ya ha borrado al hijo puedes acabar haciendo un *double delete* con consecuencias nefastas para tu aplicación:

```
QWidget* parent = new QWidget;
QWidget* child1 = new QWidget(parent);
QWidget* child2 = new QWidget(parent);

delete child1; // ok;
delete parent; // ok
delete child2; // double delete
```

Así que mi consejo es que siempre que sea posible le dejes a Qt gestionar la vida de sus objetos.